# Is there a filter to programmatically change the HTML tab switching output of the page editor?

Tags: filters

I am wondering if Wordpress allows us to change the onclick attribute of the tab switching in the HTML editor? For example this is the a tag for the Visual editor:

```
<a onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" id="content-tmce">Visual</a>
```

I would like to know if we can easily change the value of the onclick attribute using filters? Or any other means..

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to set it default to visual editor and remove the tabs ??

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with help of jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.switch-tmce').trigger('click');
});
```